# Can't create Careers profile

Tags: support, jobs

I have the same problem as some other users. When I'm trying to create my Careers Profile, I get this message:
"That email address is already registered on another account".

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry about that, you should be all set.